# Python, dataframe : Duplicating rows according to the number of items in a list and ranking the resulted rows

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have as an output of my python script a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
id1           id_list
1            [10,11,12]
2            [14,15,16]    
3            [17,18,19]
```

I would like to duplicate rows to as much as items that `id_list` contains, and attribute to every item in that list a rank corresponding to its position in the list.

The output I am looking for is as follows :

```
id1          id2           rank
1            10             1       
1            11             2   
1            12             3   
2            14             1   
2            15             2   
2            16             3   
3            17             1   
3            18             2   
3            19             3
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rebuild the data frame with `numpy.repeat` while flattening the list columns at the same time:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain
pd.DataFrame({'id1': np.repeat(df.id1.values, df.id_list.str.len()),
              'id_list': list(chain.from_iterable(df.id_list)),
              'rank': [i for r in df.id_list for i, _ in enumerate(r, start=1)]})

# id1   id_list rank
#0  1        10    1
#0  1        11    2
#0  1        12    3
#1  2        14    1
#1  2        15    2
#1  2        16    3
#2  3        17    1
#2  3        18    2
#2  3        19    3
```

Or maybe slightly more efficient:

```
import numpy as np

(pd.DataFrame([iv for r in df.id_list for iv in enumerate(r, start=1)], 
              columns=['id_list', 'rank'])
 .assign(id1 = np.repeat(df.id1.values, df.id_list.str.len())))
```

Comment: The second one works perfectly, thank you. The first one is good but it duplicates also the indexes, it doesn't increment them.

Comment: I modified the first option so that it gives unique indexes, it should work as well now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
In [176]: lst_col = 'id_list'

In [177]: pd.DataFrame({
     ...:     col:np.repeat(df[col].values, df[lst_col].str.len())
     ...:     for col in df.columns.difference([lst_col])
     ...: }).assign(**{lst_col:np.concatenate(df[lst_col].values)}) \
     ...:   .assign(rank=[i+1 for l in df[lst_col].str.len() for i in range(l)])
Out[177]:
   id1  id_list  rank
0    1       10     1
1    1       11     2
2    1       12     3
3    2       14     1
4    2       15     2
5    2       16     3
6    3       17     1
7    3       18     2
8    3       19     3
```

PS it should work also for generic DataFrames with multiple columns